# error con la api Blocked by CORS policy

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

Estimada Red,

Estoy intentando consumir una API publica creada con asp.net core, y me manda el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código en visual studio es el siguiente  :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: mi código es demasiado grande para ingresarlo escrito por eso subo imagen

Comment: Las imagenes no sirven en el sitio, no se ven y son dificiles de indexar. ademas no se pueden copiar ni nada... entonces, no sirven. Si tu codigo es demasiado largo, tenes que hacer un [mcve]. y por favor, tu error tambien debe estar en la pregunta. Si no, va a terminar cerrada...